# Generate a simple access code to view account information

Tags: hash, encryption

I need to create a website that allows customers to view their account status information online. To avoid the hassle of creating customer website accounts I'd like for them to simply log on with their account number and an access code. I would like the access code to be generated from the account number and I will provide the code on their mailed statements.

What is a good formula/function/method to generate this access code from a 8 digit numeric account number? The result could be numeric or alpha but I wouldn't want it to be more than 10 characters. I'd like to keep the math fairly simple so the code can be generated via a crystal reports formula when printing the statements. I'm not looking for bulletproof security as this isn't sensitive information. I just want to prevent someone from randomly keying account numbers in.

Comment: Can you do any sort of hash (SHA-1) from a crystal report, or generate random numbers? Or are you just looking to do some straight forward maths? Can you store something on your side (think a salt) for authorizing them when they log in?

Comment: Unfortunately I am interfacing a data dump from a legacy billing system and am trying to avoid storing anything extra other than the data file I get. That's why I wanted the access code to be based off the account number. That's also why I was trying to generate it at statement run time in Crystal. Looks like Crystal doesn't support hash functions so simple math is probably best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is split the account number in two (using modular arithmatic) and then perform a little math on those two parts to derive the authorization code.

For example:

`I'm assuming account number is atleast 10000, if they start at 00000001, then you will have to add a step to multiply it by 10,000 (which will result in larger auth codes for the bigger account numbers) or reduce the modulus size`

Let A = account number

A mod 10,000 = X

(A - X) / 10,000 = Y

AuthCode = (X + 51) * (Y + 89)

So if the account number was 18654848:

`18654848 % 10000 = 4848`

(18654848 - 4848) / 10000 = 1865

(4848 + 51) * (1865 + 89) = 4899 * 1954

= 9572646

Then perform that same math when the user attempts to log in and see if the auth code and that number match up.

This will make auth codes in the range of 103538 - 101384400

Comment: Nice. This will work great. Easy formula in Crystal as well. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.